# Hue (led) bulb does't turn on when put in certain lamps?

Tags: wiring, led, bulb, lamp

Just acquired my first set of Hue lights (E27 type) and to my disappointment when I put them in my bedroom ceiling lamp they do not turn on. However If I try by putting them in a ceiling lamp in the kitchen they turn on just fine.

How can I debug this? Is my ceiling lamp to old and reject LED bulb? Can there be any electrical problem with my bedroom ceiling light wiring ?

Note that all my lights are E14 type and I'm using E14 -> E27 Adapters. I thought at first the adapter was broken but it's not the issue because it works fine on my kitchen lamps.

(I also have a desk lamp E27 type in my bedroom and the bulb works fine in there as well)

This is a picture of the socket

[image: https://imgur.com/a/DkvJG]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where in the world are you?

Comment: There is a sticker indicating that the lamp must be a particular shape.  Does the Philips Hue bulb have that shape?  Fair chance it's bottoming out on the lamp bezel and as a result, is unable to screw in all the way.

Comment: My bet is on the adapter not making contact in the bedroom fixture. ?

Comment: @DanielGriscom UK. Here is a picture of the normal non led bulb that work (on the right) compared to the Hue + adapter. They look pretty similar to me. The adapter has even more point at the end so it should technically make more contact ?
https://imgur.com/a/QNu43

Comment: The important part is that the pointy bit touches with the end of the socket? Or does it also have to touch the sides?

Comment: Socket looks damaged. Does the lamp have a dimmer? If so, dimmer may not be compatible.

Comment: Called and electrician and when he checked inside the ceiling rose there was a small transformer that was reducing the power going to the bulbs and so the led bulb was not turning on because of lack of power

Comment: Marco, you should post that as an answer so the question can be seen as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a faulty chandelier (very old) ceiling lamp. Not enough power was ending up in the bulbs. Working fine for ordinary bulb but not for led